# Issue in logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, controller

In my web application, I want to set cookies, but while keeping that, i am having issues while logging out.

The Code is given below:

```
#region Logout
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Session.Clear();
        HttpContext.Session["var1"] = null;
        HttpContext.Session["var2"] = null;
        HttpContext.Session["var3"] = null;

        SetCookie("XXXX", XXXX, 30);
        return View();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Set Cookie
    private void SetCookie(string CookieName, string CookieValue, int CookieLifeDay)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies[CookieName] == null)
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Response.Cookies[CookieName];
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(CookieLifeDay);
            cookie.Value = CookieValue;
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


        }

        else
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[CookieName];
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(CookieLifeDay);
            cookie.Value = CookieValue;
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        }
    }
    #endregion
```

When i am logging out first time, it shows logout succeessfull, but when i click the back button, it enters to the last page accessed by user. while second time , i click the logout button. I can successfully logout. It has been a major issue in this web application. Any type of help is highly solicited.

Answer (score 0):

Use there to remove Session

```
  public ActionResult Logout()
    {            
         Session.Clear();
         Session.RemoveAll();
         Session.Abandon();
         return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: It says i am in an infinite loop@Imran

Comment: it removes the session. you may use action filter to check that your session is alive or not ..

Comment: Still, clicking the back button takes it to the previous page

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Authentication.Logout();
```

Comment: It says that `Authentication` has no definition for logout